# Unexpected image filters applied upon dialog dismiss

Tags: android

I am generating a dialog from an activity. When the dialog OK button is clicked, by using an interface I call a method in the activity, setting the color filter below. On the next line, I use dialog.dismiss(), the dialog closes and the color filter reverts back to its original XML value. Why is this happening?

XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/penColorButton"
    android:background="@drawable/some_image"
    android:onClick="showColorPickerPen"
    android:tint="#000000"
    android:tintMode="multiply"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
```

Java:

```
ImageButton penColorButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.penColorButton);
penColorButton.setColorFilter(0xffff0000); // red
penColorButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xffff0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This is before the dialog opens:

[image]

After I click OK, running the code that changes the filters:

[image]

Upon Cancel, dismissing the dialog:

[image]

The foreground filter is reset and not only is the background one kept but it's also applied to the other button.